# Perl DBI and temporary tables

Tags: perl, db2, dbi

I am using the Perl DBI and DB2.

When I run this code:

```
sub MergePolygonNameTable()
{
   my $table = "THESCHEMA.NAME";

   print "Merging into ${table} table. ", scalar localtime, "\n";
   eval
   {
      $DbHandle->do("
      declare global temporary table session.TEMP_NAME
      (POLICY_MASTER_ID INT
      )
      ;
      ");

      $DbHandle->do("
         CREATE UNIQUE INDEX session.TEMP_NAME_IDX1 ON session.TEMP_NAME
         (POLICY_MASTER_ID ASC
         )");
     $DbHandle->do("
      insert into session.TEMP_NAME
      (POLICY_MASTER_ID
      )
      SELECT pm.ID as POLICY_MASTER_ID
        FROM THESCHEMA.POLICY_MASTER pm

      ");
      $DbHandle->do("
      MERGE INTO THESCHEMA.NAME as t
      USING session.TEMP_NAME as s
         ON t.POLICY_MASTER_ID = s.POLICY_MASTER_ID
      WHEN MATCHED
      ) THEN
      UPDATE SET t.UPDATED_DATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT
      (POLICY_MASTER_ID
      ) VALUES
      (s.POLICY_MASTER_ID
      )
        ;
      ");
   };
   if ($@)
   {
      print STDERR "ERROR: $ExeName: Cannot merge into ${table} table.\n$@\n";
      ExitProc(1);
   }
}
```

The problem is that the THESCHEMA.NAME is empty after the run.

I suspect that DBI does not keep the contents of the temporary table after the do().  But the DBI does not allow me to put more than one statement in a do().

How do I get temporary tables to work in the DBI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` is the default option of the [DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-declare-global-temporary-table).
Use the `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` option to preserve the rows upon explicit or implicit `COMMIT`.

Like this:

```
      declare global temporary table session.TEMP_NAME
      (POLICY_MASTER_ID INT
      )
      ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
      ;
```